# Shell script command output differes from command line output

Tags: linux, shell

OS: RHEL 7.3. I am running below command :

```
ps uax | grep 'elasticsearch' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

If I run this command on terminal, I get one PID of Elasticsearch process. However if same command I put inside a shell script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(ps uax | grep 'elasticsearch' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
echo $PID
```

I get several PIDs one below other. What could be going wrong?

Full script which launches ES is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$ES_HOME" == "" ]; then
        echo "ES_HOME environment variable does not exists. Please set it to home dir of Elasticsearch and try again"
fi;

PID=$(ps aux | grep "elasticsearch" | grep -vE "start|grep" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs)
if [ "$PID" != "" ]; then
        echo "Elasticsearch is already running with PID: $PID"
        echo ""
        exit;
fi;

echo "Starting Elasticsearch"
sh $ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch.sh > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Better use `pgrep elasticsearch`

Comment: @GillesQuenot: Yes, or maybe `pgrep -u "$LOGNAME" -f elasticsearch` or similar.

Comment: ... don't use `grep -v grep`, instead use `grep [e]lasticsearch`, that way `grep` will not see its own process.

Comment: Or, dependent on grep, `grep -C elasticsearch` (I don't know about uax). Or, maybe you have `pidof elasticsearch`.

Comment: What name did you give to the file that contains your bash script ?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I used pgrep -f "elasticsearch". Still I am getting some additional PID in the output, when run from within the script :-(

Comment: @ottomeister You were right. My script was showing its own PID as well. Script name was `start-elasticsearch.sh`. So now I added another exclusion. Final expression `PID=$(ps uax | grep 'elasticsearch' | grep -vE "start|grep" | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: @Shades88: Does this mean you're trying to get the PID of a child process your script started?  If so you can just directly get it.  Show us how the script launches elasticsearch....

Comment: @JohnZwinck Please see my edited question, I have added startup script there

Answer (score 0):

In your script you are running it in `bash shell` `#!/bin/bash`, just check what is your current shell when you execute manually. If different change the shell accordingly. Otherwise I do not see any difference. Also check what user ID you are using while running the script.

Comment: When you need the output of a command, don't use syntax that was made obsolete decades ago.  Instead, use `var=$( cmd )`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thanks. It is a new learning for me. I don't even knew about it. :-) .

Answer (score 0):

if `pgrep` is unavailable on your machine, you can use `ps` without `grep` to get only the `pid` of a process using its `name`.

For example,

```
 #!/bin/bash

_pid=$(ps -C NetworkManager -o pid=)
echo "$_pid"
```

`NetworkManager` is the name of the command that one will see in the process table, when using `ps`. You can replace that with `elasticsearch`.